# Should the ~/tmp folder belong to me or root?

Tags: permissions, tmp

I was trying to run `yeoman` under my user, when I got errors when it tried to access `/home/adityamenon/tmp`. I checked the permissions and it turns out `~/tmp/` belongs to root.

So I changed the user and group to myself, but was this the right thing to do? Who should `~/tmp` belong to?

Also, when I'm booting, I get an error message about `/tmp/` not being mounted... if that info helps.

Comment: `/tmp/` is owned by root en must be owned by root. `/home/adityamenon/tmp` (is the same as `~/tmp` since ~ means your home directory) is owned by you. Those are TWO different directories you are looking at.

Comment: Sorry, edited my question. The final sentence does talk about /tmp/ though, but I guess that's a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~/tmp` directory, that is, a directory called "tmp" in a user's home directory, is not mentioned in any file hierarchy standards. Given that it's in *your* home directory it probably should be owned by *you*.